# is there any way that I can lessen the line of this code

Tags: python

```
grade = float(input("Input: "))
if grade <= 60 or grade > 100: 
    print ("Invalid Grade")
elif grade > 60 and grade <= 74.9: 
    print ("failing grade")
else: 
    print ("Passed!")
```

Comment: That looks to me about as short as it ought to be. What actually is the concern? There are tricks that could be used to write something shorter, but they don't actually make the code *less redundant* and might be harder to read.

Comment: You... could. This is one line: `print("Invalid grade" if 60 <= (grade := float(input("Input: "))) > 100 else "failing grade" if grade > 60 and grade <= 74.9 else "Passed!")` Now, the question is _should you_ ?  As @KarlKnechtel pointed out, there's nothing wrong with your code, and if someone reads it, it's much more straightforward and easy to understand than a convoluted one-liner that will get no improvement in performance or... well... or anything whatsoever.

Comment: You don't actually need the `grade > 60` condition, as it's already accounted for in the first if.

Comment: When you say "lessen the line", you mean lessen the *number* of lines, right? Cause you could *shorten* two lines by using chaining: `if not 60 < grade <= 100:` and `elif 60 < grade <= 74.9:`.

Comment: @BorrajaX Beside the point, but `60 <= grade > 100` is wrong; it doesn't account for `grade <= 60`. The correct condition for that is `not 60 < grade <= 100` like I wrote above, or of course, `grade <= 60 or grade > 100`.

Comment: As an aside, make those floats (60. instead of 60, etc...) to avoid the small overhead of converting the int to a float.

Answer (score 1):

Number of conditions you have will give this minimal number of if-else block. But you can try complex conditional one liner like this

```
grade = float(input("Input: "))
s = "Invalid Grade" if grade <= 60 or grade > 100 else ("failing grade" if grade > 60 and grade <= 74.9 else "Passed!")
print(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list of remarks with a calculated index based on the number of tiers the input grade clears. Use a modulo of 3 to make the highest tier fall back to index 0 for an invalid grade. With this approach, your code would be more easily scalable when there is a need to increase the number of tiers:

```
grade = float(input("Input: "))
print(['Invalid Grade', 'failing grade', 'Passed!'][sum(grade > i for i in (60, 74.9, 100)) % 3])
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/CarelessPutridAutocad

Answer (score -1):

Conditional expressions, `:=` operator, and streamlining your second condition (your first condition failing means we know `grade` is greater than `60`).

```
print('Invalid Grade' if (grade := float(input('Input: '))) <= 60 or grade > 100 else \
      'failing grade' if grade <= 74.9 else \
      'Passed!')
```